# Spark crashes due to column value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have ORC formatted data in S3, and after reading data into dataframe (I am using python/pyspark) and when I want see the content (`df.show()`) or using any other operations (like aggregations and then trying to convert it to pandas) it crashes. After a long investigation I found out that if I drop a column (`Id` in my case which has "string" data type), the crashing will not happen !! So it seems that the problem is in the values in the  `Id` column. But how should I solve this problem properly when I can not see the content of `Id` column? I need the `Id` column in my further analysis.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- profileId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sentAt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- delivered: string (nullable = false)
 |-- openedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- open: string (nullable = false

df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://loc/data")
```

Here is the error I got from Spark:

```
....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 94, in rdd
    jrdd = self._jdf.javaToPython()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o622.javaToPython.
```

Comment: can you update the question with the code you are trying and the schema of the dataframe ?

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya : I just updated the question and added the code

Comment: Maybe you are running out of memory? What is the size of `df`?

Comment: @Marioanzas: It is 305101246 rows and based on the given schema it is 305101246* (40+8+4+8+4)/(1024*1024*1024) = 18 G . The driver of my spark cluster has 60 G and I I use 4 slave nodes with 16 G memory each

Comment: It is for sure "profileId" field that causes crashing as when I drop it the error disappears. Any idea what is wrong?